# Combine 2 for loops

Tags: android, for-loop, android-listview, jsoup, baseadapter

I parse 2 elements, TD tags from a website by doing 2 for loops with JSoup.
I want them to diplay next to each other in a Listview, like this:

```
naam: waarde 
naam: waarde
```

But they are shown like this in the Listview, which gets filled by a CustomBaseAdapter.

```
naam: 
naam: 
naam: 
waarde 
waarde 
waarde
```

Can somebody please help me to get this done? This is keeping me busy for quit some time now.

Any other suggestions are also welcome, thank you.

The 2 for loops, with which the lists, "naam" and "waarde" get filled:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpn);  
   Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(0)"); 
   Elements tdsFromSecondColumn1 = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(1)"); 
   SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults(); 

      for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) {                            
           sr1 = new SearchResults(); 
           sr1.setNaam(tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 
           results.add(sr1); 
      } 

      for (Element tdFromSecondColumn1 : tdsFromSecondColumn1) {                              
           sr1 = new SearchResults(); 
           sr1.setWaarde(tdFromSecondColumn1.text()); 
           results.add(sr1); 
      }
```

I know it should be something like this, but how?:

```
for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) {                             
     sr1 = new SearchResults();  
     sr1.setNaam(tdFromSecondColumn.text());  
     sr1.setWaarde(tdFromSecondColumn1.text());
     results.add(sr1);
```

}

Here is my CustomeBaseAdapter:

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 

private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList; 

private LayoutInflater mInflater; 


  public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) { 
  searchArrayList = results; 
  mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); 
  } 


public int getCount() { 
  return searchArrayList.size(); 
} 

public Object getItem(int position) { 
  return searchArrayList.get(position); 
} 

public long getItemId(int position) { 
  return position; 
} 

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    ViewHolder holder; 
  if (convertView == null) { 
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null); 
    holder = new ViewHolder(); 
    holder.txtNaam = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.naam); 
    holder.txtWaarde = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.waarde); 

    convertView.setTag(holder); 
   } else { 
 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
 } 

 holder.txtNaam.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getNaam()); 
 holder.txtWaarde.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getWaarde()); 

 return convertView; 
} 

static class ViewHolder { 
  TextView txtNaam; 
  TextView txtWaarde; 
} 


}
```

Edit:
I have now someting like this but get exception indexsize 12:

```
public ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults(){

          ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
          ArrayList<SearchResults> results1 = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
          ArrayList<SearchResults> results2 = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

          Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpn);  
          Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(0)");
          Elements tdsFromSecondColumn1 = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(1)");

          SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
          SearchResults sr2 = new SearchResults();


          for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) {                             
               sr1 = new SearchResults();  
               sr1.setNaam(tdFromSecondColumn.text());  
               results.add(sr1);  
          }  

          for (Element tdFromSecondColumn1 : tdsFromSecondColumn1) {                               
               sr2 = new SearchResults();  
               sr2.setWaarde(tdFromSecondColumn1.text());  
               results1.add(sr2);  
          }  

          for (int i = 0; i < results.size();i++) { 
              results.add(results.get(i));
              results2.add(results1.get(i)); 
            } 

          return results2;

         }
     }
```

Edit2:
Exception is gone but it only shows the of results1 i.a setWaarde:

```
public ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults(){

          ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
          ArrayList<SearchResults> results1 = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
          ArrayList<SearchResults> results2 = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

          Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpn);  
          Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(0)");
          Elements tdsFromSecondColumn1 = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(1)");

          SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
          SearchResults sr2 = new SearchResults();


          for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) {                             
               sr1 = new SearchResults();  
               sr1.setNaam(tdFromSecondColumn.text());  
               results.add(sr1);  
          }  

          for (Element tdFromSecondColumn1 : tdsFromSecondColumn1) {                               
               sr1 = new SearchResults();  
               sr1.setWaarde(tdFromSecondColumn1.text());  
               results1.add(sr1);  
          }  

          for (int i = 0; i < results.size() && i < results1.size();i++) { 
              results.add(results.get(i));
              results2.add(results1.get(i)); 
            } 

          return results2;

         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to what Chris said. Also, if you're trying to combine those two loops, you can't do it with that syntax. Just use the simple counting method, e.g.

```
for(Object o : oList1) {
    doStuff(o);
}

for (Object o : oList2) {
    doStuff2(o);
}
```

becomes

```
for (int i = 0; i < oList1.size() && i < oList2.size(); i++) {
    doStuff(oList1.get(i));
    doStuff2(oList2.get(i));
}
```

Of course, this assumes the two lists are the same length, otherwise one of the lists won't be fully consumed. If they vary, you COULD use OR instead of AND in the loop and check each one for null before acting on it, but you're probably better off just using two separate loops.

Comment: Hi kcoppock,
Ok, thx for the tip tried it, see edited code, but i got exception ivalid index size 12.

Comment: You didn't try what I showed. `results1` must be larger than `results` per your exception; you're never checking to make sure your index is within the boundaries of `results`.

Comment: Ok kcoppock,
I admit i am lost now but i accept your answer anyhow.
Could you give an example what you mean exactly?
I am not an loop expert, sry for that.

Comment: You don't need to accept it if your problem isn't solved. I gave an example of what I mean. In the loop condition, I check to ensure `i` is less than the size of BOTH of the lists. In YOUR example, you are only checking against the size of results1. Say for example there are 5 items in results1, and 3 items in results2. The loop will continue once `i` is 3 because it's less than results1's size. However, there IS no item at index 3 in results2, since there are only 3 items in the list, so your program crashes.

Comment: Hmm ok, exception is gone, please see my edited code.
It now only shows the setWaarde items in the listview.
This loop problem is keeping me busy now for 2 weeks.

Comment: Personally, I think you should step back, sleep on it maybe, and come back and think through your logic. The reason you're only seeing the setWaarde items is because you're only returning results2 in your `GetSearchResults()` method. `results` is left to die.

Comment: I honestly don't mean that in a negative way, either. After looking at your own code for a while, it's easy to look over that sort of thing. Taking a break can help with that.

Comment: I understand youre point of view but i am stepping back an sleeping over it already for 2 weeks now.
I realy appreciate youre help in this but a solve code would realy help, if that`t applicable in my case.
I just need to see the logic behind the solving code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating a new `SearchResults` object each time you go through each loop.  It's fine to create a `SearchResults` object during each iteration of the first loop, but you need to use the `SearchResults` object created in the first loop for the second loop, don't create a new one.

Comment: Hi Chris,
Thx for replying, could you please show me how to get this done with my code in the for loops?
I already tried several combinations but it won`t work.
I`m realy desperite.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!, after taking advise from kcoppock to step back a little while, having a beer and a sigaret the solution was easier as i thought:

```
public ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults(){

          ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

          Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kp);  
       // Get all td's 
          Elements waardes= doc.select("td"); 
       // Iterator over those elements      
          ListIterator<Element> postIt = waardes.listIterator(); 

          SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();

          while (postIt.hasNext()) { 
                sr1 = new SearchResults();
                // Add the value text to the ArrayList      
                sr1.setNaam(postIt.next().text()); 
                sr1.setWaarde(postIt.next().text());  
                results.add(sr1); 
            } 

          return results;

         }
     }
```